# Sealed interface nested classes which implement interface, not recognised as valid type by IDE

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, aar

I'm publishing an `aar` library that contains Kotlin source files, and that relies on (sealed) interfaces.

```kotlin
interface SampleResult {
    object SampleOneSuccess: SampleResult, OperationOne

    object SampleOneError: SampleResult, OperationOne

    object SampleTwoSuccess: SampleResult, OperationTwo

    object SampleTwoError: SampleResult, OperationTwo

    sealed interface OperationOne

    sealed interface OperationTwo
}
```

Function generating `SampleResult`:

```
fun doOperationOne(): SampleResult.OperationOne {
    return if (true) {
        SampleResult.SampleOneSuccess
    } else {
        SampleResult.SampleOneError
    }
}
```

This code compiles, and when interacting with `doOperationOne()` in the original project I'm not getting any IDE warnings. Notice how the IDE shows that `OperationOne` and `OperationTwo` are interfaces that have an implementation (the green arrow to the left of them):

[image]

### Packaging and consuming in different project

I then package this as an `.aar` file and publish this on Maven, along with the sources as `.jar`. In a new project, I add the distributed package as a dependency, and I run:

```
val x = doOperationOne()
if (x is SampleResult.SampleOneSuccess) {
    Log.e("TAG", "x is SampleResult.SampleOneSuccess")
}
```

I get IDE warning `"Condition 'x is SampleResult.SampleOneSuccess' is always false"`:
[image].

However at runtime, the log is printed.

(and attaching a debugger, it confirms that `x` is of type `SampleResult.SampleOneSuccess`)

Furthermore, source inspection shows that the IDE no longer recognises `OperationOne` and `OperationTwo` as `sealed interfaces` that have an implementation (notice the lack of green arrow to the left of these two interfaces):
[image]

What have I tried:

- assembling the .aar with with a different Kotlin version (both 1.7.21 and 1.9.0 produce the same problems)
- removing the parent `SampleResult` (so the if-statement becomes `if (x is SampleOneSuccess)`). This works, but is not what I want.

I fail to understand what the reason for this problem is. Is this hierarchy too complex to be able to successfully represent? Is something going wrong in the `.aar` and `.jar` artefact creation?

Source code: https://github.com/SammyO/SealedSDKTest

- `com.oddhov.sealedsdktest:app:0.2` shows a broken version
- `com.oddhov.sealedsdktest:app:0.3` shows a version that works (by lifting the sealed interfaces out of the parent interface)

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can show IDE integration features, like the green arrow? I've tried to limit the reliability on images and write as much text as possible, but if you have suggestions on how I can improve it, I'm happy to hear it :)

Comment: @Jorn I updated my post to have more code samples

Comment: not a solution, but to inspect the type hierarchy you could have a look at the `Type Hierarchy` in Intellij